# Jquery BxSlider plug in help creating custom left & right arrow to go through slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am using the Jquery [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) plugin. What I am trying to achieve is the EXACT same example that is shown on [this page](http://bxslider.com/). I know how to create the slider, I am struggling to link my left and right arrow to go to the pre/next slides. Please can someone help, I can imagine it is a very simple solution.

I have a

```
<a href="" class="bx-prev">PREVIOUS</a>
```

the javascript somehow needs to say when that class is clicked go to the previous slide.

[Here is their API page](http://bxslider.com/options)

my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#saucesslider').bxSlider({
    autoControls: false,
      });
});
  $(".bx-prev").click(function(){});
</script>
```

Comment: what does "struggling" mean..struggling with what ?. The source and css are avaialable for inspection in a browser console. Put a demo of what you have so far in jsfiddle.net so people can try to assist. Without any live html and css you won't likely get much help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it´s all on the page you linked to. no need to set prev and next links yourself, the script will do that for you.

- include jquery
- include bx slider js
- include bx slider css

put each slide in a list item.

check out jsfiddle.net/zCAMC/1/

Comment: you have the same problem as me. theres no left button?

Comment: copy and paste the Jsfiddle into a .html file and see for yourself what the problems are. there are no left and right buttons